# CDH Security using Kerberos and Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to secure my CDH cluster using Kerberos but I want to use the user info that I have in my Microsoft Active Directory. 
Is there a way to use MS AD as Kerberos user lookup source?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MS AD is actually an umbrella set of technologies working together to provide enterprise directory services.  The big four, as I call them, are Kerberos, LDAP, DNS and Group Policy.  Each MS AD domain controller runs a Kerberos KDC, which is a database of user, service, and computer principals.